# Django - Is ManyToManyField required to use over ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-models

I've inherited a legacy database and am using it for a Django app.

Many of the internal tables have one to one, one to many and many to many relationships.  In a straight SQL app, the data queries would use foreign keys to maintain referential integrity.  In Django, a `ManyToManyField` method is declared.

Is it strictly necessary to use ManyToMany over ForeignKey?

Answer (score 1):

`ForeignKey` and `ManyToMany` are two different things. You probably mean `ForeignKey` v/s `OneToOne`

An example:

Lets take some arbitrary `Developer` model

```
class Developer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User) #ensure there is a one-to-one relationship between User and Developer model - One user object in django.contrib.auth can be associated with only one Developer and vice versa 
    category = models.ManyToMany(Category) #Developer can be part of many categories, and also one category can be associated with many developers
    birth_address = models.ForeignKey(Address) #He can have only birth place. The address can be associated with many, so it is a `OneToMany` relationship
```

So, [`ManyToMany`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) is many-to-many relationship and [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) is a restricted `ManyToMany` (a many-to-one relationship).

So, you can use either one, but might be a good idea to restrict to `ForeignKey` if you wish to restrict the number of objects that can be associated with the Model in question